# Can Google Cloud Data Catalog link to Azure Data Lake and Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, catalog, google-data-catalog

Is it possible to use the Google Cloud Data Catalog to catalog an Azure Data Lake, Blob storage or Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Google cloud Data catalog doesnot support Azure services directly. But it supports creating custom Data Catalog entries, with this we can ingest any metadata from anywhere.

https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/custom-entries

Also they developed some sample connectors, similarly you can build connectors for AWS services.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datacatalog-connectors

Sample

https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-data-catalog-integrate-your-on-prem-rdbms-metadata-468e0d8220fb